# Sitecore 8.2: New "Customers and Orders Manager"

Tags: sitecore, e-commerce, sitecore8, sitecore8.2

Does anybody know the prerequisites to see any users in the new SPEAK tool(which was added to lanchpad after installing of the corresponding package) "Customers and Orders Manager"? I tried to add a user to CommerceUSers domain, but I couldn't see these users in this tool. Have I missed something?

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I found that we have a new index in Sitecore 8.2 - "commerce_userprofiles_index_master". I rebuilt it and now can see the users in the manager. Sorry for disturbing.